# Processesing JSON data, Iphone Versus Android

Tags: android, iphone, json

Fetch back a JSON record JSON:

```
{
    content : [
        { action : "eat ice-cream", username : "tom" },
        { action : "play sport", username : "mike" },
        { action : "dancing", username : "dan" }
    ],
    message : "OK",
    status : 1
}
```

Iphone:
The Object would contain an action and username field.
In the callback function

```
-(void) fetchdatacompleted:(NSDictionary*)dict
{
    if([dict objectForKey:@"content"] != nil)
    {
        [objectArray removeAllObjects];

        if([[dict objectForKey:@"content"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]])
        {
            NSArray *array = (NSArray *)[dict objectForKey:@"content"];

            for (NSDictionary *dict in array)
            {
                myobject = [[Object alloc] initWithDict:dict];
                [objectArray addObject:myobject];               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***How does Android handle the above processing?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) and [JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html).

Example:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray content = json.JSONArray("content");

for (int i = 0; i < content.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject entry = content.getJSONObject(i);
    // and so on...
}
```

Comment: you saying if you do JSONArray content = json.JSONArray("content"); then JSONArray would contains the content : [
        { action : "eat ice-cream", username : "tom" },
        { action : "play sport", username : "mike" },
        { action : "dancing", username : "dan" }
    ],   On Iphone it runs through the array and grab individual object to build up the objectArray.   Seems like you just grab all that data and put into the array in one swoop in android.

Comment: `json.JSONArray("content")` is equivalent to `(NSArray *)[dict objectForKey:@"content"]`. Both platforms fill the whole array with the data.